# Intersection of k + 1, k sized sets is not empty, therefore the Intersection of all sets is not empty.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A_j \subseteq X, j = 1,2, \cdots, N$ sets of size $k$ each, different each, and the Intersection of each $k + 1$ of the sets is not the empty set.

> Prove that the intersection of all $A_j$ sets is not the empty set.

**Edit**: We have tried many things, trying to prove it, by induction, by contradiction, etc but nothing comes really close.

Comment: Is it union or intersection or am I missing something

Comment: You were correct, the question has been edited, thank you.

Comment: One more edit is needed, union has to be changed to intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\bigcap_{i \leq N}= \emptyset$. For simplicity assume $A_1 = \{1, ..., k\}$. For each $l =1,...,k$ there exists an $A_{i_l}$ with $l \notin A_{i_l}$. Now $A_1 \cap \bigcap_{l \leq k}A_{i_l}=\emptyset$ contradicting the assumption about $k+1$ intersections being non-empty.